# Ctrl+1 does not work in OneNote 2016

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, to-do, microsoft-onenote-2016

I'm using OneNote 2016 from Office 365 on my ASUS N552VW laptop. The keyboard shortcut Ctrl+1 to set the To-Do tag does not work on my laptop:

[image]

I tried the left and right Ctrl keys, tried 1 on the numpad keyboard - nothing helped. Ctrl+2 does not work too, but other Ctrl+digit combinations work.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a known problem?

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason why it did not work. It was my fault. I set the Ctrl+1 and Ctrl+2 keyboard shortcuts in my Windows 10 to quickly switch languages:

[image]

I removed those special shortcuts, and now OneNote works as expected. Love this tool!

Answer (score 2):

I made a workaround:

- Add the "To-Do" button to your Quick Access Toolbar by clicking the dropdown arrow on the very top of your screen.
- Now move the "To-Do" button to be the very first one.

And now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will do it.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. However, I asked about `CTRL`, not `ALT` :)

Answer (score 0):

Alt + 3 worked for me when Ctrl + 1 stopped working.   Give that a try if you do not want to do thru the config changes.

Answer (score 0):

**My "tags" list was empty for some reason - I added a checkbox item manually** (named it Checkbox and selected one of the available checkbox icons.

Then I noticed that OneNote had added Ctrl+1 to it automatically (since it was the first and only item on the list) and it now works!

[image: tag symbols popup]

[image: tags list]